# How to change the automatic debug code loaded in a launch.json file in VS CODE (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debugging

So when I open vscode to debug each time i have to change this part of the launch.json . How can I set it to the following code so I do not have to do that task.

```
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
```

How can I set it to the following code so I do not have to do that task.

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/Adventure Game.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"  //this is the code i want it to be
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks